# How to run Java source file with multiple packages using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a beginner of Java and Eclipse. Now I have a Java plugin and its source file. I want to debug the source file in Eclipse to see how each part of the code runs. I created a new project named first trial, and the structure is like this:

```
src\analyser: 1.java,2.java,3.java...
    GUI: 1.java,2.java,3.java,4.java,5.java...
    GUIPanelWindow: 1.java...
    main:1.java...
    segmentation: 1.java...
    tracking: 1.java
```

There are more than 5 classes in each package. It's based on the third party-Fiji, so at the beginning of each class it shows the syntax like this "import ij.Prefs","import ij.plugin.PlugIn" and so on.I have also added external JAR files into the library, but it also shows the error "The import ij cannot be resolved ". Thus, the result of debug shows that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at main.LineageTracker.main(LineageTracker.java:320)
```

I want to know if I can debug a Java source file like this or what other steps I should do? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Is ij only a JAR file or do you have the full source for it?

Comment: Check you **Build Path**. Are external JARs included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on PM 77-1's comment, assuming `ij` is in one or more JAR files, here's how to add those JAR files to your Build Path (tested on Eclipse Kepler, the most recent version):

- Right-click on your project (`first trial`) in the Package Explorer.
- Select the `Build Path` submenu.
- Choose `Add External Archives`.
- In the resulting `JAR selection` dialog, choose the JAR files for `ij`.  You can select more than one file.
- Hit OK.
- The JARs you selected will appear in the Package Explorer, below `src`, under `Referenced Libraries`.
- Build and hopefully it will work!